# Remove commits from unreferenced branch

Tags: git, git-flow, git-workflow

I'm trying [Git Workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) before adoption. After a whole release cycle I have ended with this branch tree. (c: commit, m: merge)

```
master      v0 - - - - - - - - - - m1 
                                   |
release                  - c3 - c5 - 
                        |           |
development v0 - c1 - c2 - c4 - - - - m2 - c6
```

After version 0 `development` continue to `c1` and `c2`.

After `c2` a `release` branch was created.

```
git checkout -b release development
```

`development` branch evolved to `c4` while `release` branch evolved to `c3` and `c5`.

After `c5` I merged `release` into `master`

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff release
```

and into `development`

```
git checkout development
git merge --no-ff release
```

then `release` branch was deleted

```
git branch -d release
```

Only `master` and `development` branches exist now. I thought that `c3` and `c4` commits in old `release` branch will be removed from history and I would end up with linear `master` and `development` branches. `c3` and `c4` are included in `m0` and `m1` commits so there is no need to keep then.

Now in Bitbucket if I inspect only `master` branch I get this tree:

```
master      v0 - - - - - - - - - m1 
                 |               |
                 |    - c3 - c5 - 
                 |   | 
                c1 - c2
```

While I expected just:

```
master v0 --- m1
```

And this is the one for `development`:

```
                     - c3 - c5 - 
                    |           |
development v0 - c1 - c2 - c4 - m2 - c6
```

While I expected:

```
development v0 - c1 - c2 - c4 - m2 - c6
```

**Is there any way to avoid this?**

**Can this situation be fixed now?**

Comment: When you merge, you can squash all of the commits into a single commit instead of preserving commit history. I don't recommend doing that on a regular basis, though.

Comment: Background reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452

Comment: Use `git log --first-parent master` to view your branches, if you remove the history from git, things become hard to figure out where something got changed when there is a problem

Comment: Really nice option. It really helps to show main branches log uncluttered with extra commits.